# Is there an overview over all OAuth2-related specifications?

Tags: oauth

I recently started to read up on OAuth2, and just now noticed how many extensions exist to this protocol. Is there an overview or some kind of a map of OAuth2 and all of its (official) extensions? I was hoping that something like in the diagram below somewhere existed.

[image: OAuth2 and extensions]

If no such document exists, then I would like to know which official OAuth2 extensions there are. I could only find an official site for OAuth1 extensions.

I know of the following extensions:

- The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage
- OAuth Assertion Framework
- OAuth JWT Assertion Profiles
- OpenID Connect protocol suite
- SAML 2.0 Profile for OAuth2.0 Client Authentication and Authorization Grants

Answer (score 1):

I found quite useful the diagram represented under the openid website [OpenID Connect Protocol Suite](http://openid.net/connect/). You can click on the boxes in order to see the specification

[image]